# How do you check the mimetype of a file uploaded to your server?

Tags: python, django, linux, file, unix

it's just a user upload a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UploadedFile.content_type

Check http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs for more info

Answer (score 3):

**UploadedFile.content_type** will return the content-type header that was sent with the file when uploaded at the time of upload.

If you also need to check files after they are saved you can use the **mimetypes** module in python. But it appears to only check based on the **file extension**.

```
import mimetypes
file_type, file_encoding = mimetypes.guess_type('/path/to/file')
print 'File-type: %s\nFile-encoding: %s' % (file_type, file_encoding)
```

And if you have file-type requirements that are not detected by default you can add the types to mimetypes simply too before using **guess_type**:

```
mimetypes.add_type('font/ttf', '.ttf')
```